# Alternative colouring on filtered rows VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I want to alternate colour rows in a filtered table by their value in Column A.

The expected result would be

-row 2-3 (column A value=1) will get one colour e.g. yellow

-row 4 (column A value=2) will get another colour

-row 5-6 (column A value=3) will get yellow again

How can I do this in filtered table using VBA?

Comment: you could just do conditional formatting, no need for VBA

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the condition for colouring here is value being Odd or even. You could try,

```
Sub AlterColour()
Dim intRowCount, intLastRow, intValue, intPreValue as Integer


intLastRow = Application.CountA(Sheets(1).Range("a:a"))

'Set first row to a colour 
Sheets(1).Range("a" & 1 ).Interior.ColorIndex = '[An Integer Here, index 36 for yellow]

'Note: inteRowCount = 2 if there is no header, otherwise set to 3
For intRowCount = 2 to intLastRow

intValue = Sheets(1).Range("a" & intRowCount ).Value
intPreValue = Sheets(1).Range("a" & (intRowCount - 1) ).Value

If intValue = intPreValue Then 
     Sheets(1).Range("a" & intRowCount ).Interior.ColorIndex = '[An Integer Here, index 36 for yellow] 

Else 
     Sheets(1).Range("a" & intRowCount ).Interior.ColorIndex = ' [An Integer Here, index for other colour] 

End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for your code. My condition for colouring is based on any change in value, not odd or even though. (context banding)

Comment: You're welcome, I edited the code. It should now change the colour if the value of the cell doesn't match the previous cell's value. If, in any case, by change in the value you meant compared to the first row, then you could change the IF condition to : If intValue <> [First Row Value]. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying to alternative colouring for filtered row, in this case how should I change your code to do it?